# Сделать модальное окно на размер экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня , нажав на кнопку, открывается модальное окно прям очень огромное и скролл и тд...  А надо , чтоб на любом экране ( на любом экране монитора, телефона и тд ) открывалась как на картинки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  // Get the modal
                        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

                        // Get the button that opens the modal
                        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

                        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
                        btn.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "block";
                        }

                        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                        span.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                        }

                        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                        window.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                        }
                        }
                        
                        

                                let mc = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
                                console.log(screen.availWidth,' ',screen.availHeight)
                                mc.style.width = screen.availWidth + 'px';
                                mc.style.height = screen.availHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
 
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
 
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
 
                        <!-- The Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
 
                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                        </div>
 
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот кусок кода уберите, и всё будет ок:

```
let mc = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
console.log(screen.availWidth,' ',screen.availHeight)
mc.style.width = screen.availWidth + 'px';
mc.style.height = screen.availHeight + 'px';
```

А чтобы контент занимал всю высоту экрана, добавьте ему height: 100vh (и box-sizing: border-box, чтобы не было скролла):

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
 
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}
 
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
 
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: он тогда открывается не на такую высоту как мне надо. он должен почти весь экран занимать на любом монике , а так он тогда будет как маленькое окошко по середине

Comment: @XXXXXX, добавьте контенту height: 100vh (я дополнил ответ)

Comment: понял , спасибо